# error delayed_job in server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Error sending e-mail at Delayed Job.
It displays the following error:

Job Mailer.newsletter (id=2) FAILED (8 prior attempts) with Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your mailer configuration first ,have you set correct host and port in the mailer configuration?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Without this component, functions normally